# convex Hull Trick

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geometry

I am trying to solve codechef (Oct15) long challenge(https://www.codechef.com/OCT15/problems/JUMP). It uses convex hull trick (http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick).

My understanding is :

1. the lines are sorted according to the slopes in the descending order
2. if the line of intersection between the lines L3 and L1 is left to the lines of intersection of L1 and L2 , then we remove L2 from the stack .
   correct me if i am wrong.

what i doesn't understand is :

1. max or min y - coordinate also depends on its y-intercept , so how could we do things based on only slope?
2. Is it any ways related to the convex hull algorithm ?

   also could some one provide any link to the implementation details of the trick used

Comment: You will not do everything based only on slopes, you will just use the slopes to sort the lines.

Comment: Please state *in the question* what you are trying to do. We don't like questions that depend on linked documents.